# How to create a moving handle for a custom user control in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I'm working on a custom control. This control is more like container (Panel), And has some other controls in it's bounds. And the should be able to add controls to it at design time. it means that it shouldn't be dragged from anywhere. If you take a look at the top left corner of `Panel` you will understand what I mean.

How to achieve this in my control?

Comment: that functionality comes from a `ControlDesigner` using `SelectionRules`

Comment: I have figured that out just right now. but how to use it? I Don't Have This Property in my user control

Comment: you have to write a `SuperPanelDesigner` for your control which inherits from `ControlDesigner`.  there you set the `SelectionRules`.  you'll need it for SmartTags too

Comment: thank you very much. and how can I associate it with my control?

Comment: using the `<Designer()>` attribute

Comment: You are my hero. thanks a lot Plutonix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `Plutonix`, I have found my answer. It could easily done by inheriting the ControlDesigner from `ParentControlDesigner` class.